# Is there CSS to select blockquote only if it is the first element in a div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm working on a design for a blog. Is there a css selector (or other way that doesn't involve the user adding a class or id to a blockquote tag) that will allow me to differentiate between a blockquote that occurs at the very beginning of a div from a blockquote in the middle of a div after some text blocks?

That is, I'd like blockquotes that are the start of a blog post to have one set of css styles, and blockquotes that occur in the body of a blog post to have other style parameters.

Is this possible?

Comment: @RodneyFolz The problem presented by that question is different to this one, as that one tries to select the first child with a specific class (and not necessarily the actual first child) whereas this wants the very first child.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply:

```
div > blockquote:first-child {
    ...
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6qY8P/).

This combines the [child combinator (`>`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#child-combinators) with the [`:first-child` structural pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#structural-pseudos) to select the `div` element's direct child `blockquote` element only if that element is the first child.

To then style `blockquote` elements which aren't the first child, you'd simply use the `div > blockquote` selector, as this has lower specificity than the one above.

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for `nth-child` by the sounds of it.

Read this: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/